Map of global sections surjective under a local condition
Let $M$ be a compact complex manifold and $p \in M$. Let $L \to M$ be a line bundle on $M$ and $\mathcal{F}_{\{p\}}$ be the sheaf of holomorphic sections of $L$ that vanish at $p$. Locally around a neighborhood of $p$ with a frame $s$ we can write any section $\tau \in \mathcal{F}_{\{p\}}(M)$ as $\tau =fs$. We can therefore define a map $F: \mathcal{F}_{\{p\}}(M) \to \bigwedge^{1,0}T^*_pM$ by $F(\sigma)=F(fs)=df_p$. I'm trying to prove the following

The map $F: \mathcal{F}_{\{p\}}(M) \to \bigwedge^{1,0} T^*_p M$ is surjective if and only if for every nonzero $v \in T^{1,0}_p M$, there exists a section $\tau \in \mathcal{F}_{\{p\}}(M)$ that can be expressed in a neighborhood of $p$ as $\tau = fs$, where $f(p) = 0$ and $vf \ne 0$.

If we assume that $F$ is surjective and let $v \in T^{1,0}_p M$ be nonzero we can choose $\alpha \in \bigwedge^{1,0} T^*_p M$ for which $\alpha(v) \ne 0$. By the assumption there exists $\tau$ such that $F(\tau) = \eta$ and also $\tau = fs$ locally as well as $f(p) = 0$. And so $vf =df_p(v)= F(\tau)(v)=\eta(v) \ne 0$.
For the other part I'm a bit stuck. If we take local coordiantes $z^k$ in a neighborhood of $p$, then any $\alpha$ can be written as $\alpha = \sum c_kdz^k|_p$. We need to come up with a section $\tau \in \mathcal{F}_{\{p\}}(M)$ that maps under $F$ to $\alpha$. If we consider $v_j = \frac{\partial}{\partial z^j}$, these are all non-zero and by assumption there exists $\tau_j \in \mathcal{F}_{\{p\}}(M)$ such that around a neighborhood of $p$ we can write $\tau_j = f_j s$ with $f_j(p) =0$ and $v_jf_j \ne 0$. If I set $$\tau = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \tau_j = \sum_{j=1}^n a_jf_j s$$ then
$$
F(\tau) = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j df_j = \sum a_j \frac{\partial f_j}{\partial z^j}dz^j
$$
and I would be done if I could only guarantee to pick $a_j$'s such that $$a_j\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial z^j}=c_j$$ for each $j$. Can I do this? I think that the assumption gives $\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial z^j} \ne 0$ so $$a_j = \frac{c_j}{\frac{\partial f_j}{\partial z^j}}$$ should be well-defined?
